# Backing up mail accounts without full access to mailserver

Tags: email, pop3

I'm in the process of migrating some stuff from a (crappy) hosting. Files were easy with SSH access, but mail is giving me some thoughts.
This is the situation:

- qmail server, no ssh access
- I own postmaster account
- accounts are accessible via web interface or POP3
- I'm interested in transferring emails, but if whole accounts can be transferred it'd be better.

Being POP3 I'm fairly confident every message has been downloaded, but of course I'd like to download the whole thing to be safer.

Right now I have this in mind:

- Enter in web admin
- Change each account's password (it's only a dozen or so accounts so still feasible)
- Send new password to user telling him please not to change it
- getmail or something like that
- put on new IMAP server in some way (which I still haven't planned)

But I feel there should be a better way to do this. Is there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as transferring the data is concerned, those are pretty much the steps. getmail works and I'm sure there are a million other tools to do this via POP/IMAP too. Some hosting companies will export your mail for you for a fee and send it on DVD or something but if it is a POP account, getmail is as good as anything. Obviously next steps are to get a new mail somewhere and change your MX records at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought that if I create the new accounts in advance I can just do it in one step, so even less hassle.